# Mac OS X, unable to un/mount Macintosh, password appears

Tags: mac, hard-drive, password, recovery, internet-recovery

[image]I was trying to reinstall OS on my old Macbook Air 2015. Then, I erased all the data from it and something happened Macintosh HD get greyed out, and get encrypted. I tried many other solutions on Internet, but I still has a problem. It just can't get unmounted, uncrypted or something else. When I trying to reinstall Mac OS El Capitan it asks about password on Macintosh. I did not set any passwords or other stuff. And everytime when I click cmd + r it opens in Internet Recovery(cos I wipe the disk). Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you let us know exactly which error/password screen[s] you see. there are some here - https://support.apple.com/HT204156

Comment: If you wiped the entire disk, then you have removed the Recovery Partition, so the only option is Internet Recovery. You need to be more precise about exactly what the messages are and when you see them.

Comment: I don't know how to add more photos. But, I updated the post with main problem

Comment: there's the link on imgur @Tetsujin https://imgur.com/a/uyV3vyL

Comment: Sorry, I can't tell from those pictures what you did, in what order. As already mentioned, if you've wiped the HD, then you need Internet Recovery.

Comment: It is already Internet recovery. I just can't mount disk, or interact with it. I can't download OS, cos it is requires password:(

Comment: See how you get on with https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos/309400#309400 You're not really adding enough information to work with.

Comment: I just don't know, what can I add more. Maybe Macintosh just bricked up?

Comment: Take it to an Apple Store. They'll put an OS on it for free.